# Rails rendering a new object as an edit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have an application where I'm creating a new object via a "new" action.  Rails is using the correct controller action, and also rendering out the new form correctly.

However, the path for the form is coming up with an Id for an edit which is breaking things.  The form tag is just:

```
<% form_for @issue do |f|
```

etc

Any ideas as to why this would be an edit form instead for a new one?

Controller looks like this:

```
class IssuesController < ApplicationController
  layout 'application'

  def new
    @issue = Issue.new
  end
end
```

Routing is as follows:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :issues
end
```

Comment: Can you show us your associated controller code and route definitions please.

Comment: i'm a little confused as to what you mean by "form is coming up with an id." Meaning you get redirected to "myapplication/controller/new/id"? Can you tell which .erb file you are getting sent to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `=` sign here is the guy that breaks your stuff!

```
<%= form_for @issue do |f|
```

Comment: pretty sure you don't want to add the `=` sign. 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html